# c++ multithread slow processing

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have multiple consumer threads and one producer thread. Producer thread writes the data into a map belong to a certain consumer thread and sends a signal to the consumer thread. I am using mutexes around the map when I am inserting and erasing the data. however this approach looks not efficient in terms of speed performance. Can you suggest another approach instead of map which requires mutex locks and unlocks and I think mutex slows down the transmission.

Answer (score 2):

> however this approach looks not efficient in terms of speed performance. Can you suggest another approach instead of map which requires mutex locks and unlocks and I think mutex slows down the transmission.

You should use a profiler to identify where the bottleneck is.

---

> Producer thread writes the data into a map belong to a certain consumer thread and sends a signal to the consumer thread.

The producer should not be concerned what kind of data structure the consumer uses - it is a consumer's implementation detail. Keep in mind that inserting a value into a map requires a memory allocation (unless you are using a custom allocator) and memory allocation internally takes locks as well to protect the state of the heap. The end result is that locking a mutex around `map::insert` operation may lock it for too long actually.

A simpler and more efficient design would be to have an atomic queue between the producer and consumer (e.g. [pipe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pipe.html), [TBB concurrent_bounded_queue](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/hh_goto.htm#reference/containers_overview/concurrent_bounded_queue_cls.htm) which pre-allocates its storage so that push/pop operations are really quick). Since your producer communicates directly to each consumer that queue is one-writer-one-reader and it can be implemented as a wait-free queue (or ring buffer a-la [C++ disruptor](https://code.google.com/p/disruptor-cpp/)).

Comment: Can you suggest some implementation example of these queues? Are they standard in STL or somewhere else? Do you mean std::atomic?

Comment: @AvbAvb I added a couple of references.

Answer (score 0):

Andrei Alexandrescu made the good point in that you should measure your code (https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/three-optimization-tips-for-c/10151361643253920) and this is the same advice I would give you, which is to measure your code and see what performance differences you are getting between a baseline test and your test running single threaded:

1. Time required to insert data using single thread to map
   with above listed data
2. Time required to insert data
   using single thread to map with above listed data and using mutex
   locks

If you are still looking for a thread-safe container, you may want to look at **Intel's open-source** implementation of **thread-safe containers** at http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_queue_cls.htm .

Also, as a suggestion for the consumer thread implementation, you may want to read the **ActiveObject** article that **Herb Sutter** posted on his website: http://herbsutter.com/2010/07/12/effective-concurrency-prefer-using-active-objects-instead-of-naked-threads/

If you can provide some more details, like why the map has to be locked all the time, we may be able to draft up a mechanism that is better performing.